# Icon disappears when page is dragged to second monitor

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, url, icons

I can't find anything, anywhere for this one.

I have an icon for a button, and the URI to that icon is in the CSS. When the browser is on the laptop screen it calls the correct URL for the icon, but when the browser is on a second screen connected to the laptop it makes a call to a different URL and gets a 404, and the icon disappears. I can drag the browser from one screen to the other and the icon will dynamically show up and disappear, depending on what screen the browser is on. It does this on multiple machines, including Windows and Mac. What could be causing this?

Comment: Please post your code, else it's difficult for anyone to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're not using a media-query with another URL depending on the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have pixel density difference between those monitors, this could cause the stylesheet to bring another image, usually a @2x image to fill the extra pixels that "retina" monitors can have.

maybe you have a rule on your responsive css matching the `max-width` or `min-width` of the page.

It's really hard to know, can you provide a link for the website?